# Java Endless While Loop

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, infinite-loop

I have the following code:

```
boolean[] usedInts = {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false};
for(int i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
    JLabel square = squares[i];

    // Declare coordinate
    Coordinate coordinate = null;

    boolean keepGoing = true;
    while (keepGoing) {
        // Get random number
        int rand = generateRandom();

        if (usedInts[rand]) {
            keepGoing = true;
        } else {
            // Save that we used it
            usedInts[rand] = true;
            keepGoing = false;
        }
        // Initialize coordinate
        coordinate = coordinates[rand];
    }

    // Set square coordinates
    square.setLocation(coordinate.getX(), coordinate.getY());
    // Set used to true
}
```

The problem is that the `while` loop is endless and the `else` part only runs 8 times.
What is going on here?

Comment: You need to give us some more code. Currently we don't know what `coordinates` is, what `square` is. As it stands, the question is quite vague to be answerable.

Comment: How does `generateRandom` work?

Comment: @Jeffrey That is the true question here...

Comment: If you are trying to generate random permutation of coordinates then you might find that Collections.shuffle method is more convenient way to do this (unless you have very special requirements for random generator).

Comment: `getRandomNumber()` => `new Random().nextInt() % 9`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only possibility I see is that your `generateRandom` method generates numbers in range 0..7 (only 8 numbers, not 9) or 1..8 for example

Comment: You and me Tala, we've got this haha

Comment: Yep. StackOverflow saved years in total for developers :))))

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing its because your generateRandom function isn't returning a correct range.

Answer (score 0):

Add the **generateRandom** method so we can fix your problem.